# React Cant Access Class Scope on Event Handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a react component which is a text input. When someone pressed enter it must call myMethod(). However in handleKeyPress, I can not access class scope. How can I fix this ?

```
class MyContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);        
    }

   myMethod(){}


    handleKeyPress(target) {
        var self = this;
        if(target.charCode === 13) {
            this.myMethod();
        }
    }

    render() {
        <input onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}  ref={(input) => this.inputMax = input} type="text" />
    }
}
```

Comment: for that you need to **bind** the `handleKeyPress`, put this line in the constructor: `this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)`

Comment: See also: http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html - 6 alternatives listed, choose one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the handler.

```
class MyContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    }

   myMethod(){}


    handleKeyPress(target) {
        var self = this;
        if(target.charCode === 13) {
            this.myMethod();
        }
    }

    render() {
        <input onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}  ref={(input) => this.inputMax = input} type="text" />
    }
}
```

Another solution can be to use an arrow function (which has performance drawbacks) or an [`@autobind` decorator](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the function in the constructor.

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)
}
```